# CSS applies after pressing CTRL + F5, but on next action it doesn't, until I press CTRL + F5 again

Tags: html, css, browser-cache

I am developing an web application using .NET Core. I have a table where I have made some CSS changes. On some html table cells `<td>` I have added a CSS class.

```css
.text-right_custom {
   padding-right: 30% !important;
   text-align: right !important;
}
```

When I open the page, it doesn't reflect my changes. When I hit CTRL + F5, it refreshes with my CSS applied. But when I make another action, it gets back on first version, without my CSS applied. When I hit CTRL + F5 than everything work, until next action. Something that might be useful, when I open inspect element when my CSS hasn't been applied, I see two CSS classes. Can anyone help me solve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server? If yes then please share the link. Thanks

Comment: I haven't, sorry.

Comment: I've never had this problem but it could be a cache problem. With chrome, when inspector is open, click on the circular refresh arrow with right button and select empty cache and... etc (my browser not in english)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about .NET. But I think it's a problem with cache. If you are using chrome press ctrl+shift+i(that will open up your console. At console on Network tab check the input field named "Disabled cache". When you open refresh the page keep the console open. If you use any version number on CSS then remove all the version number during the developemnt mode. Hope this helps.